# React Material UI 1.0 Select multiple params onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm working with React Material Ui 1.0.0-beta.34 and I have a problem with Select component.
I'm trying to set additional parameter to `onChange` event handler but it looks like only event parameter is allowed to be passed. This is how my custom Select component looks like.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Input, { InputLabel } from 'material-ui/Input';
import { MenuItem } from 'material-ui/Menu';
import { FormControl, FormHelperText } from 'material-ui/Form';
import Select from 'material-ui/Select';

class CarSelect extends Component {

    render() {
        const {classes, value, cars, onSelectChange} = this.props;

        return(
            <FormControl>
                <InputLabel htmlFor="car-helper">Car</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    value={value}
                    onChange={onSelectChange}
                    input={<Input name="car" id=car-helper />}
                >
                    {cars.map(car => {
                        return (
                            <MenuItem key={car.carId} value={car.carId}>{car.registration}</MenuItem>
                        )
                    })}
                </Select>
                <FormHelperText>This is required!</FormHelperText>
            </FormControl>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(CarSelect);
```

And my container looks something like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as carActions from '../../../redux/aircraft/carActions';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context)

        this.state = {
            form: {
                car: {
                    carId: ''
                }
            }
        }

        this.handleSelectChange = this.handleSelectChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.cars.length == 0) {
            this.props.cars.loadAll();
        }
    }

    handleSelectChange = (event) => {
        let target = event.target;
        let report = Object.assign({}, this.state.report);
        report[event.target.name][event.target.name + 'Id'] = event.target.value;
        return this.setState({report: report})
    }

    render() {
        const { cars } = this.props;
        return (
            <CarSelect value={this.state.form.car.carId} cars={cars} onSelectChange={handleSelectChange}  />
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        cars: state.Car.cars
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        cars: bindActionCreators(carActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default withStyles(styles) (connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Form));
```

So I'm trying to pass additional parameters to my `handleSelectChange` function but I don't know how because Material UI 1.0 `Select` component callback `onChange` only pass through the event object. Does anybody know how to pass additional parameters?

Comment: Have you tried `onSelectChange={(e) => handleSelectChange(params, e}`

Comment: You can also create your callback using currying. ```handleSelectChange(params) { return (e) => { /*do things with e and params*/ }}``` and in your view: ```onSelectChange={handleSelectChange(params)}```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass an expanded lambda function into the prop:

```
handleSelectChange = (event, carId) => {
    // do things with event and carId
}

render() {
    const { cars } = this.props;
    return (
        <CarSelect
            value={this.state.form.car.carId}
            cars={cars}
            onSelectChange={(evt) => handleSelectChange(evt, this.state.form.car.carId)} 
        />
    );
}
```