# How to send event and object as parameters to Javascript eventlistener function?

Tags: javascript

So I'm writing Javascript and using a Material Ui Select component.
This component has a parameter "onChange" which triggers if a new drop-down item is selected.

```
onChange={(event) => {
    let newObj = {
        'param1': value1,
        'param2': value2,
        ...
    }
    handleChangeTemplates(event, newObj);
}}
```

When debugging the function "handleChangeTemplates", it receives the "event" object correctly, but does something weird (to me anyway) with the other object. Here's how it looks during debugging:

[image: valuesObject image]

How can I properly send all my parameters that I need to the function, during the "onChange" event?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how whole code looks like but valuesObj somehow pointing react element.

I have created same component in code sandbox an it working fine. Please check that, It may help.

https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-material-demo-forked-mnc45?file=/demo.js

Comment: It somehow doesn't seem to work, it keeps saying it's a React Element... I've found this as well in the meantime: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49114768/react-material-ui-1-0-select-multiple-params-onchange , which looks the same, but somehow it works for you both and not for my code :s

Comment: @Tempuslight if possible just create a code sandbox link of your code, So that I can check the code or screen shot of select component also help. I can see somehow whole react component is passing as data.